# Initial Value in angular toSignal()

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, signals

I have a problem with a signal, I can't set initialValue:true (TS2769: No overload matches this call.)

However, the Observable does return an Observable.

I solved the problem by removing the "initialValue" option and adding "as Signal" but I find this not a satisfactory solution because I don't understand why it doesn't work.

If you have comments on the use of signals and my code in general, I am also interested :

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly injector = inject(Injector);

  constructor(private scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher,private viewportRuler:ViewportRuler) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.scrollLimit = toSignal<boolean>(this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()
      .pipe(
        map(()=> this.viewportRuler.getViewportScrollPosition().top),
        map((top) => top < 349)
      ), {injector: this.injector, intialValue: true}) ;
 }
}
```

here is my unsatisfactory solution which works

```
    this.scrollLimit = toSignal<boolean>(this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled()
      .pipe(
        startWith(void 0),
        map(()=> this.viewportRuler.getViewportScrollPosition().top),
        map((top) => top < 349)
      ), {injector: this.injector}) as Signal<boolean>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly scrollDispatcher = inject(ScrollDispatcher);
  private readonly viewportRuler= inject(ViewportRuler);

  scrollLimit = toSignal<boolean>(this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().pipe(
    map(()=> this.viewportRuler.getViewportScrollPosition().top),
    map((top) => top < 349)
  ), { initialValue: false })
}
```

OR this:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly scrollDispatcher = inject(ScrollDispatcher);
  private readonly viewportRuler= inject(ViewportRuler);

  scrollLimit = toSignal<boolean>(this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().pipe(
    startWith(0),
    map(()=> this.viewportRuler.getViewportScrollPosition().top),
    map((top) => top < 349)
  ), { requireSync: true })
}
```

Comment: thx, requireSync works, but doesn't initialValue

Comment: initialValue works, but whitout the generic type